# SQL Server comparison operations in ON eg: on a>b, output not as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have a question using sql server and wonder if anyone can help:
Below is my query:

```
select distinct a.*, b.*

from table_a a
left join 
(select * from table_b where number_ in ('1','2') ) b
on (a.id=b.id 
and cast(a.date_ as date)>= cast('2021_12_01' as date))
```

However,by looking at the results I got, it doesn't seem like a.date>= cast('2021_12_01' as date) was working, I noticed the output date has values smaller than 2021_12_01. Can anyone help me understand what went wrong?

I tested the individual statement using below and it successfully filtered the dates, not sure why it was not working in the "on"clause:

```
select * from table_a
where cast (date_ as date)>= cast('2021_12_01' as date)
```

table_a

| id | date_ | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-07-16 11:59:09.000 | 20 |
| 2 | 2022-07-16 10:59:09.000 | 290 |

table_b

| id | date_alert | number_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-14 10:03:02.000 | 2 |
| 2 | 2020-01-14 10:05:02.000 | 2 |

I expect the result to only include id 2 related info since it's date_2 is larger than 2021/12/01

Comment: use a proper date format as your query must give an error https://dbfiddle.uk/3XXfiN47

Comment: not it didn't, I tested that where statement individually and it worked fine @nbk

Comment: use an iso format 2021-12-01 and you still need so that all need to be true that the ids match for both tables and have the correct date

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Why are you casting `date_` to a `date`, is it *not* already a date and time data type? If it is (a date and time data type) the `CAST` to a `date` achieves nothing. Both `'2021-12-01T00:00:00` and `'2021-12-01T23:59:59.999` are *both* >= `2021-12-01`. If it isn't (a date and time data type) then the problem is your design; you need to fix that.

Comment: @Larnu, pls see the updated question. I can confirm problem is not related to the time data type because I tested that statement individually, my confusion comes from as why the cast (date_ as date)>= cast('2021_12_01' as date) is not working in 'on" clause

Comment: @TheImpaler please see my updated question and let me know for any questions, thanks

Comment: Two things: 1) What is the actual type of the `date_` column as configured on the server? Datetime? Varchar? DateTime2? 2) The date comparison seems to belong more semantically with the `WHERE` clause rather than the `ON` clause. You'll get identical results either way, but it's odd to have this in the `ON` clause when it only references the left-hand side table.

Comment: Just do `WHERE a.date_ >= '20211201'`. There's no need for any of that `CAST`ing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*, b.*
FROM Table_A a
INNER JOIN Table_B b ON a.id = b.id AND b.number_ in (1,2) 
WHERE a.date_ >= '20211201'
```

The biggest change relative to the question is moving the date comparison to the `WHERE` clause. It's based on this information:

> I noticed the output date has values smaller than 2021_12_01.

If the comparison is part of the `ON` clause for a `LEFT JOIN`, then **it's expected** that *every row of `Table_A` will be included*, even for dates smaller than the desired `2021_12_01`. If you want to exclude those rows, as seems the case, you need to either move the condition to the `WHERE` clause or change to an `INNER JOIN`. (I did both, because it seems like that's the expected result, but leaving this as a `LEFT JOIN` is still an option, and an easy change to revert — just change the one word.)

Other changes:

1. Converted the sub query to JOIN directly to the table with an additional JOIN condition
2. Converted the `'1','2'` literals to numbers. I *certainly hope* a column named `number_` is *not defined as a varchar*, so this change should help improve performance by improving index use and reducing data conversions.
3. Used the [correct date literal format](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2022/07/13/sql-and-dates/#Formats).
4. Removed the `cast` on `a.date_`. Again, I certainly hope a column named `date_` is *not defined as varchar!* Given that assumption, and also knowing that casting a `datetime` to a `date` truncates any time portion, we can logically know that comparing whether any `datetime` value is greater than or equal to a given date at midnight will give **same result** as comparing the truncated version of the datetime, meaning the cast was *not necessary.* Removing it can **dramatically** improve performance by again reducing conversion operations and improving index use for the query.